# Django CompositeField subclass not overwriting __unicode__ method

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-composite-field](https://bitbucket.org/bikeshedder/django-composite-field) to create a currency field that includes both a dollar_value and a dollar_year (i.e., "$200 in 2008 dollars").

I have the following models in a Django app:

```
#models.py
from composite_field import CompositeField

class DollarField(CompositeField):
    """ Composite field to associate dollar values with dollar-years."""
    dollar_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    dollar_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False, 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1980),
            MaxValueValidator(2020)])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.dollar_year+"$: $"+self.dollar_value # "2012$: $149.95"

class ProductStandard(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    standard_level = models.ForeignKey(StandardLevel)
    price = DollarField()
```

When I access the `price` attribute of a `ProductStandard` instance, I expect to see a formatted string like this: `2012$: $199.99`. Instead, I see `DollarField(dollar_value=Decimal('199.99'), dollar_year=2012)`, which is the return value of [the CompositeField `__repr__` method](https://bitbucket.org/bikeshedder/django-composite-field/src/398e3be0a96111212b71abce3b95fd306a1f4228/composite_field/base.py?at=default). But since I've sublassed CompositeField and added my own `__unicode__` method, shouldn't Django overwrite? Or am I misunderstanding something?

I'm using Django 1.5.4 with Python 2.7.3 and django-composite-field 0.1.

Comment: Did you try returning a `unicode` ? `return u'%s$:$%s' %(self.dollar_year, self.dollar_value)`

Comment: `__unicode__` is for returning a Unicode human-readable representation (similar to `__str__`). `__repr__` has other uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The `__repr__` you are seeing is actually not a `__repr__` of a CompositeField, but of it's Proxy (refer to composite_field/base.py, line 104). So you would have to provide your own proxy, and override the `__repr__` method there, like so:

```
class DollarField(CompositeField):
    """ Composite field to associate dollar values with dollar-years."""
    dollar_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    dollar_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False, 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1980),
            MaxValueValidator(2020)])

    def get_proxy(self, model):
        return DollarField.Proxy(self, model)

    class Proxy(CompositeField.Proxy):
        def __repr__(self):
            return "%s$: $%s" % (self.dollar_year, self.dollar_value) # "2012$: $149.95"
```

of course, if you would like to leave `__repr__` as it is, you can override `__unicode__` instead of `__repr__`, like you did. The difference is that:

```
print(mymodel.price)
```

would call the `__repr__`, while

```
print(unicode(mymodel.price))
```

would call the `__unicode__` method.